# Is this code a fit candidate for an ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

```
public ActionResult Index(int ehrId, int? page)
{
    EHR ehr = ehrRepository.FindById(ehrId);
    if (ehr.UserName != User.Identity.Name)
        return View("Invalid Owner");

    var physicaltests = ehr.PhysicalTests.Where(test=>!test.IsDeleted).OrderByDescending(test => test.CreationDate);
    List<PhysicalTestListItem> physicalTestsVM = new List<PhysicalTestListItem>();
    Mapper.Map(physicaltests, physicalTestsVM);
    var paginatedTests = physicalTestsVM.ToPagedList(page ?? 0, PAGESIZE);// new PaginatedList<PhysicalTestListItem>(physicalTestsVM, page ?? 0, pageSize);
    return View(paginatedTests);
}

public ActionResult Create(int ehrId)
{
    EHR ehr = ehrRepository.FindById(ehrId);
    if (ehr.UserName != User.Identity.Name)
        return View("Invalid Owner");

    return View(new PhysicalTestForm());
}
```

I have absolutely all of my methods inside my `PhysicalTestsController` performing these three lines of code before execution. How can I refactor this to avoid so much repetition? I have only included two of my methods but there are actually six methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would think so**

An Action Filter would be appropriate for validating input data.

Eg

```
EHR ehr = ehrRepository.FindById(ehrId);
if (ehr.UserName != User.Identity.Name)
  return View("Invalid Owner");
```

Would be appropriate to put in an Action Filter, I have created other Input Validation as in [Requires Login] or [RequiresSSL] in the past so that multiple actions can share the same code (onBeforeExcuting, or onAfterExecuted).

**Aspect Oriented Programming for Cross Cutting Concerns**

However other things such as Logging which is a cross cutting concern across all layers of your architecture, you may want to look into AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) to help avoid duplication of code there.

- http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/07/14/CustomActionFilterLoggingApplicationBlock.aspx

**Update - Sample Code (Untested)**

```
public class CheckValidUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      IMyRepository myRepository = IoC.Resolve<IMyRepository>();
      Int64 userId;      
      if(Int64.TryParse(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["id"]), out userId))
         if(!IsValidUser(userId))
            filterContext.Result = new InvalidUserResult();   
     }

     public bool IsValidUser(IMyRepository myRepository, Int64 userId)
     {
       EHR ehr = ehrRepository.FindById(ehrId);      
       return ehr != null && ehr.UserName == User.Identity.Name;
     }
}
```

Something like the above should do it, you'd need to create a named view to return your "Invalid User", however that should be trivial.  There should be plenty of examples on the net on how to create and use Action Filters.  Personally I learnt from Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework and

- http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/15/partial-output-caching-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Is reflection required to get ehrId if you use an Action Filter?

Comment: @BZink - No reflection is not required TMK, however there is added complexity that you have to retreive values from an ActionExecutedContext or ActionExecutingContext to retreive the action parameters (ehrId in this case).

Comment: Thanks for that very complete answer.. Im definitely trying to learn as much as we can... would you mind sharing a little code so that I have an idea on how i could make this actionFilter work?.. is it okay to reference repository inside the actionfilter?. thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen people use IoC.Resolve<IMyRepository>() in action filters before.  Just be sure that you abstract the actual call inside the Action Filter away so it can be unit tested.

Comment: @NachoF - I've updated my answer with a quick and dirty (note untested) action Filter as an example of what you could do in that case.